# Decrypte an image over server using php which is encrypted by blowfish algo in java

Tags: php, encryption, blowfish

I have an image which is encrypted by java code this is the code used in encryption https://gist.github.com/madan712/19996a6107d2f2b5f928

i want to decrypt this image on my server using PHP i tried following but none of them is working for me am new to this please help me out

here is the code

```
function decrypt_blowfish($data,$key){
  $iv=pack("H*" , substr($data,0,16));
  $x =pack("H*" , substr($data,16)); 
  $res = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $x , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
  return $res;
}

$img =decrypt_blowfish(file_get_contents('https://srv-file20.gofile.io/downloadStore/srv-store1/t1pusI/1017_5_20_20200904_131827_%24%24%24%24_e869deffe072cc122960c9711947c2a5_0%2340000_0%23.jpgob'), 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@d97ad201');
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($img).'"/>';
```

I tried this code to decrypt the image string but still getting corrupted image please help me out with code

Comment: What is this `'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@d97ad201'`? You're mistaking a Java reference for the actual key bytes. That's probably not the key you're looking for

Comment: Try to run your decrypt function with the key "DesireSecretKey" (without quotation marks)

Comment: @ArtjomB this is the key provided by java dev to me

Comment: am not familiar with Java but these are the 2 things provided by the dev to me secret key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@d97ad201
cipher encrypt "mode1cipher"

Comment: @MichaelFehr   i tried that but not work for me giving me a syntax error

Comment: So, you're saying that this is just example code and you're using the correct key when you run it on your machine?

Comment: no the secret key that is provided to me is : "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@d97ad201" ,  am not sure it's key or the java ref I tried it as key

Comment: can you generate an image from that code using your any test key and I will check that on my end whether the code is working not